# Trigger volley request on Recycler view item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I'm kinda new to android and try to build a simple application. This application consist of 3 pages, categories , products and detail product. The category page is requesting data from an API using voley and display it in a recycler view. My question are, how i can trigger another volley request on recycler view item click ( when someone click a category ). Any sample code or tutorial links will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think when "category recycler view item click", just go to products page which I designed as a "Activity", and "send another volley request" in that page. Most of time, I send a request in that Activity's "onResume " function

Comment: what you mean is, start a new intent with category_id as a parameter and then trigger a volley request on that activity , is that right ?

Comment: Yes, it's ok for you?

Answer (score 2):

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
   List<movie> mDataset;
    public static final String JSON_URL = "url"


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        sendRequest();





    }

    private void sendRequest(){


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
        JSONParse pj = new JSONParse(json);
        pj.parseJSON();
        mDataset = pj.getMovies();
        mAdapter = new myadapter(mDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

myadapter.java

```
public class myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;


    private List<movie> mDataset;
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;
        public ImageView imageView;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);


        }
    }
    public void add(int position, movie item) {
        mDataset.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
    public void remove(movie item) {
        int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    public myadapter(List<movie> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
    @Override
    public myadapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyler_card, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.text.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());





        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(mDataset.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);



    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Volley is initiating background thread(s) on its own so all the network requests are executed off the UI thread so primarily you don't need to extend AsyncTask anymore. 
 You can try the following on the same activity.

RecyclerTouchListener.java

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    Log.d("Slider", "constructer");
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {

                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    Log.d("Slider", "onInterceptTouchEvent" + gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e));
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("Slider", "onTouchEvent" + e);
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
}
```

In your Activity page use below:

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            //Get the data using position and call the function for volley request
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```